Existence of jointly measurable kernel density
Let $S$ be a complete and separable metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{B}(S)$, and let $(T, \mathcal{T})$ be a measurable space. Let $\mu: T \times \mathcal{B}(S) \to [0, 1]$ be a probability kernel. That is, $\mu(t, \cdot)$ is a probability measure on $S$ for every $t \in T$, and $\mu(\cdot, A)$ is a measurable function for each $A \in \mathcal{B}(S)$.
Now let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $S$ and assume $\mu(t, \cdot)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ for each $t \in T$. Does there necessarily exist a single measurable function $f: T \times S \to [0, \infty]$ such that
$$
\mu(t, A) = \int_A f(t, x) \, \nu(dx),
$$
for every $(t, A) \in T \times \mathcal{B}(S)$? Clearly, for each $t$, we could choose a version of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, $d\mu(t, \cdot)/d\nu$, and define this to be $f(t, \cdot)$. But can we always make those choices in such a way that the resulting function $f(t, x)$ is $\mathcal{T} \otimes \mathcal{B}(S)$-measurable?
I found a potentially similar result in Appendix 8 of Ethier and Kurtz, but it's not clear that this can be adapted to the above. And in any case, I would prefer a reference, if possible, so that I do not recreate a proof that already exists.
